# What good is the armor rating of an item?

Tags: lotr-war-in-the-north

How highly should I prioritize the armor rating of various item pieces in Lord of the Rings: War in the North? Is it worth picking up and item that has slightly less armor with a higher stat rating (dexterity or power for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How highly that you should prioritize the armor rating of various item pieces in Lord of the Rings: War in the North is dependent on your combat performance. If you're taking a lot of damage, despite your best efforts, you should prioritize armour over something such as dexterity or power. However, a difference of -1 armour for, say, +2 Dexterity when your armour value is up in the 600s, is obviously small enough of a loss in armour that it becomes difficult to decide.

You may set (a) benchmark(s). [Consider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felicific_calculus) these two benchmarks to go for, and these are just examples, not necessarily what I recommend: (1) Survive at least one hit from a troll, in terms of armour, and (2) kill a goblin sapper in one ranged shot, in terms of Dexterity. If you are going for these two things, you may decide that you should head in a straight-line for the one that you're likely to get first, to experience the benefit of one of the benchmarks ASAP, instead of trying to get both at the same time and reaching either one at the same time, which would be the slowest progress possible within reason.
On the other hand, you could make a less binary consideration that mêlée is used more often and thus more important than ranged combat, and if both benchmarks could only be achieved in the same amount of time, you should focus on the bonus that helps more in CQC.

At the end-game, I consider armour much less important, especially with Andriel. Andriel has a skill/spell that provides her with overpowered armour that's not hard to recast continuously. More importantly, you'll mainly play new-game-plus to repeat the Truesilver side-quest which becomes the most important quest in the game. The Truesilver side-quest reward allows you to inlay runes upon a piece of equippable gear, adding several attributes: Reduced Wear 5000%, +200 Armor & +20 Dexterity (on armour), and +90 Damage and +200 Crit Damage (on weapons). I assumed that runes can be inlayed on a piece an indefinite amount of times. One of the best WitN players that I know (OnLive's "thatcoolkidiknow") told me that the max is 10, but they are rusty and I am skeptical. Even if the max is 10, the degree to which those attributes are boosted and the amount of times that you can apply them (10*(head+shoulders+torso+necklace+glove+rings*2+pants+footwear) = 90 armour applications) practically renders moot, in my opinion, any bonus that ultimately boosts vitality and (straight) damage. In turn, attributes that remain sought-for are: skill refresh cooldown reduction (my favourite), power (mana), Will, increased severing, steal power chance, chance of power orbs, stun ward, etc..
Elemental damage and other effects that I'll call "utility damage" are exempt from irrelevance-due-to-[power-creep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_creep) in that they don't merely add to the damage, but also provide a utility effect such as freezing the enemy, in the case of ice damage.